# SSRS Reports hosted in Azure Virtual Machine not available outside the VM

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-virtual-machine

I have created an ssrs report inside an Azure Virtual Machine (SQL Server 2012 SP1 on Windows Server 2012). When I try to view the report from the Virtual machine it opens up in the browser with a proper url like

```
    http://mysamplevm/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMySampleReport&rs:Command=Render
```

When I try to open the same url from my local machine, it says webpage is not available. I have completed the following settings too.

- Created Inbound & Outbound rules in Virtual Machine Firewall for port numbers 80 and 443.
- Created end points for the same port numbers in azure management portal.

Comment: Can you ping the SSRS server from your local machine?

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover I get Request time out every time I try to ping.

Comment: you CANNOT PING anything inside Windows Azure, unless part of Virtual Network.

Comment: This is not a difficult issue to fix. If via the public URL and yet its not working, have you confirmed that you can get to the server via port 80? Can you telnet to it on port 80? Is there any rules that needs to be added to allow external access?

Comment: Thanks for you reply @Chelseawillrecover. I had followed the steps described in this link [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn449661.aspx).I just deleted my old VM and repeated the entire process. Now it is working fine. But I have no idea what I did wrong the first time.

Comment: This could be a issue when you didn't open the firewall port for 80 or 443 (HTTPS) when you initially create VM, (it has option to with two default ports open as I remember one for powershell) so in order to access report server from outside you must either open HTTPS or HTTP (80) when creating VM

Answer (score 2):

You shall access the report server via the public DNS Name - this is sort of `http://mysamplevm.cloudapp.net/ReportServer/Page`, and not `http://mysamplevm/`. You can get this when you navigate to the dashboard of your VM in the management portal - right hand links are named `Quick glance`, the second is `DNS Name`.

Because your computer has no idea how to find `mysamplevm`.

Comment: I tried accessing it via the DNS link which appends **cloudapp.net** to the virtual machine name.But that also did not work for me.

Comment: The url with public DNS name is not yielding any data inside/outside the VM.

Answer (score 2):

While astaykov is correct regarding the URL, there are two more steps you need to go through to make your report server accessible from outside your VM:

1. Open HTTP/HTTPS endpoint for your VM in Azure management portal
2. Open a firewall port:

Open Windows PowerShell on your Virtual Machine

Run the following (for port 80):

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName “Report Server (TCP on port 443)” -Direction Inbound –Protocol TCP –LocalPort 80
```

Now you can access your report server from remote computers through:
http://yourservername.cloudapp.net/reportserver

Answer (score 1):

You have to log into the VM and open windows firewall advanced settings. In Inbound settings, allow port 80 to accept connections.

In addition to what DivineOps has mentioned. In Azure portal (new version), you have to go into NSG to configure firewall rules.

For me, I had to configure inbound rules, both on VM (via RDP) and via Azure portal for it to be accessible.

Comment: why this has been rated down?